# How to reset the value of counter everytime when window closes in local storage in angular?

Tags: angular

I made an app named counter app which counts the value on how many times click on the button. I am successful in storing the value when the page loads but my counter value is not reset when I close my window. Can someone suggest me something?

```
var app = angular.module('counter', [])
    app.controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope) {
        $scope.counter = localStorage.getItem('counter');
        $scope.increment = function() {
            $scope.counter = parseInt($scope.counter )+ 1;
        localStorage.setItem('counter', $scope.counter);
        };
        $scope.decrement = function () {
            $scope.counter = $scope.counter - 1;
            localStorage.setItem('counter', $scope.counter);
        }
        $scope.reset = function() {
            $scope.counter = $scope.counter = 0;
            localStorage.setItem('counter', $scope.counter);
        }
        console.log(localStorage.getItem('counter'));
    }]);
```

I changed the code to session storage from local storage but still I won't be able to reset my counter value.

Answer (score 0):

so if you wants to reset the values of your browser storage, on closing of the window. Then prefer way is to use sessionstorage instead of localstorage. Session storage persist value till the point window is not closed, as Window is closed, sessionStorage is lost. and localStorage persist the data  till the things are not cleared from browser itself.

Not much just replace:
`localStorage` with `sessionStorage`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It helps me a lot.

Comment: So if this is your answer. May you mind to take the time to mark it correct!! Thanks